# Resize with imagecopyresampled and imagejpeg not working

Tags: php, gd

I'm trying to resize a picture using the following PHP script.

```
$tn = imagecreatetruecolor(1836, 3264);
$newImage = imagecreatefromjpeg('user/354010050076877/2.jpg');
imagecopyresampled($tn, $newImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1836, 3264, 739, 1162);
imagejpeg($tn, 'MyFile.jpg');
```

The image is created at MyFile.jpg but it's still the original size.

I also tried replacing line 4 with ...

```
file_put_contents('MyFile.jpg', $tn);
```

When I try that it returns

"Warning: file_put_contents(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource in /home/content/01/7258201/html/imgTools/resize.php on line 6"

What do I need to change in my script to get image resize working?

EDIT:

I had mixed the order of values on 'imagecopyresampled' however even after switching them It's not really resizing correctly so I'm still looking for a good fix for this. [See my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15034299/773263) for more details.

Comment: What are the source and destination image sizes?

Comment: I made an edit since your comment but original is 1836x3264 and new is 739x1162.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$tn = imagecreatetruecolor(739, 1162); // the first line in your script
```

Comment: I was just about to post this

Answer (score 0):

I tested your script (that one using imagejpeg) and it works on my end. So probably something in your GD library configuration/setting ...

Comment: It runs for me and creates an image but the image that is created is not 739x1162

Answer (score 0):

Problem was I had put the wrong values for new width and height and mixed them with the old changed.

```
imagecopyresampled($tn, $newImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1836, 3264, 739, 1162);
```

to

```
imagecopyresampled($tn, $newImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, 739, 1162, 1836, 3264);
```

Thought it's still not completely working as it resizes the old image onto a larger black space.

[image]

Comment: You should edit your question instead of posting something that doesn't work as an answer. If you can't accept it, it's a comment/update.